# Features missing after updating to 14.04, how to get them back?

Tags: sound, system-settings

I'm new to ubuntu. After recently being inable to use my Ubuntu, I switched it on, and a few updates were going through.

After updates, I'm missing all this:

- my sound options from the top bar
- the sound at all, there is sound on login and while testing
- after suspending everything blocks
- a lot of information in system settings is missing, too

How can I get these back?

Answer (score 2):

System settings come back after reinstalling this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Sound is also back after

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

then running

```
pavucontrol
```

and pointing it to the right device.